# Functoriality of the adjoint functor construction?

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, functoriality

Say we have a category $\mathcal C$, and for every category $\mathcal A$, we have a category $\mathcal D_{\mathcal A}$ and a functor $F_{\mathcal A} : \mathcal D_{\mathcal A} \to \mathcal C$, and, moreover, that this is 2-functorial in $\mathcal A$.  Suppose further that $F_{\mathcal A}$ is a right adjoint for every $\mathcal A$, and call it's left adjoint $G_{\mathcal A}$.  Then we have a function from categories $\mathcal A$ to functors $C \to \mathcal D_{\mathcal A}$, sending each category $\mathcal A$ to the functor $G_{\mathcal A}$.

**Question:** Is this function (2-)functorial in $\mathcal A$?  (If yes, what is it's action on morphisms?; if no, is there an intuitive explanation of why construction of adjoints shouldn't be functorial?)

That is, given $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal A'$ and a functor $f : \mathcal A \to \mathcal A'$ (which, by assumption, induces a functor $F_f : \mathcal D_{\mathcal A'} \to \mathcal D_{\mathcal A}$ and a natural transformation $T_f : F_{\mathcal A} \to F_{\mathcal A'}\circ F_f$), do we get a natural transformation between $F_f \circ G_{\mathcal A}$ and $G_{\mathcal A'}$?

I've been staring at the universal morphism characterization of adjunctions, and not seeing how it gives functoriality.

Comment: Uniqueness of adjoints gives pseudo-functoriality.

Comment: What does "2-functorial in $\mathcal{A}$" mean? Do you mean a 2-functor $\mathfrak{Cat} \to \mathfrak{Cat}_{/ \mathcal{A}}$, where $\mathfrak{Cat}_{/ \mathcal{A}}$ is the strict slice 2-category? Or some other variation?

Comment: It seems like what you're asking is the following: "Suppose I have a cartesian fibration which is locally cocartesian, is it also cocartesian?" The answer to that question is "yes", but I may be misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The map $G_{A'} \to F_f \circ G_A$ is called the [mate](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mate) of $T_f : F_A \to F_{A'} \circ F_f$.  It's the composite

$$ G_{A'} \to G_{A'} F_A G_A \to G_{A'} F_{A'} F_f G_A \to F_f G_A$$

of $T_f$ with the unit of the adjunction $G_A \dashv F_A$ and the counit of the adjunction $G_{A'}\dashv F_{A'}$.